# Invoices note generated automatically after Stripe update

Tags: magento2, magento2.3.4, stripe

Last week, we moved from the Cryozonic Stripe modules to the newest Stripe Payments module in response to the reported security vulnerabilities. One functionality change we've noticed is that invoices are no longer automatically generated when an order is completed online. I'm wondering if I'm overlooking any configuration settings that could relate to this, or if I'd need to introduce some custom code?

Any thoughts would be very helpful, thank you.

Comment: Did get any solution for this

Answer (score 2):

Invoices would be generated when a payment is collected. If the Stripe module is configured with a payment action of "Authorize Only", the invoice must be manually created from the Magento admin area as explained at https://stripe.com/docs/plugins/magento/admin#capturing-invoices. If you need to create an invoice before the payment is collected, you will find a setting in the module configuration that looks like so:

[image]

The above only apply for card payments. For redirect-based payment methods, invoices will be created when a payment succeeded webhook arrives to your website, so make sure that webhooks are correctly configured.

Comment: I have set the payment action as "Authorize and Capture" and Enabled the webhooks, still, the invoice is not generated automatically.

Comment: @Sathya make sure your webhooks are working

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that there are some configuration settings that need to be adjusted in order to generate invoices automatically when an order is completed online with the new Stripe Payments module.
I would suggest checking the settings in the Magento admin panel under Sales > Sales Emails > Invoice, and also verifying that the "Automatically Invoice All Items" setting is enabled under Stores > Configuration > Sales > Sales Emails.
If those settings are already enabled and invoices are still not being generated automatically, you may need to introduce some custom code to achieve the desired functionality.